# toString() and accessors

Tags: java, tostring, accessor

```
public class Fan {
        public static void main(String[] args){
Fan fan1 = new Fan();
        fan1.setSpeed(FAST);
        fan1.setRadius(10);
        fan1.setColor("yellow");
        fan1.setOn(true);
        System.out.println(fan1.toString());        
    }

    // fan speed variables
    final static int SLOW = 1;
    final static int MEDIUM = 2;
    final static int FAST = 3;

    // Other fan variables
    private int speed;
    private boolean on; // true means on
    private double radius;  // radius of fan
    String color;

    // No-arg constructor
    public void Fan(){
        speed = SLOW;
        on = false;
        radius = 5;
        color = "blue";
    }

    // Mutator methods
    public void setSpeed(int newSpeed){
        if(newSpeed < 0)
            System.out.println("Illegal speed!");
        else
            speed = newSpeed;
    }

    public void setOn(boolean newOn){
         on = newOn;
    }

    public void setRadius(int newRadius){
        if(newRadius < 0)
            System.out.println("Illegal radius!");
        else 
            radius = newRadius;
    }

    public void setColor(String newColor){
        color = newColor;
    }

    // Accessor methods
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }

    public boolean getOn(){
        return on;
    }

    public double getRadius(){
        return radius;
    }

    public String getColor(){
        return color;
    }

    // toString method to output Fan data
    public String toString(){
        if(on = false)
            return "Fan is off.";
        else
            return "Fan Properties:\n" + "Fan speed: " + speed + "\n"
            + "Color: " + color + "\n"
            + "Radius: " + radius + "\n";
    }
}
```

The above piece of code is simple but I was wondering how the toString method uses the on variable even though I didn't supply parameters for that method. Also, why do we not need to invoke get methods in the main class and only need to invoke the set methods? (please explain how each method invokes one another until the final output)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure this compiles? "if (on = false)" should throw an error -- it should be "if (on == false)". I'm also not really sure what you are asking. The toString method doesn't use any getters or setters -- it directly accesses the on variable. It is able to do this because toSting and on are members of the same class.

Comment: It was actually printing the output to the screen but if the fan was off it's supposed to print "Fan is off" which didn't happen.

Comment: I changed the toString method to the following but it's still wrong. Can you please explain how to correct it?

Comment: public String toString(){
 if(on == false)
  return "Fan is off.";
 else if(on == true)
  return "Fan Properties:\n" + "Fan speed: " + speed + "\n"
   + "Color: " + color + "\n"
   + "Radius: " + radius + "\n";
 }

Comment: Very beautiful, but it does compile. After all you get a boolean variable. It is just result of the assignment.

Comment: Darth is correct, this will not compile. Also, you should never use == with a boolean... `if(on)` accomplishes the same thing. Lastly, if you are asking how toString() can access `on`, the variable is defined at the class level, therefore toString() has visibility to it.

Comment: @darthhappyface `if(on = false)` will compile with no problem, although that's not what he really is after.  The expression inside the `if` must evaluate to a boolean value. `on = false` assigns boolean `false` to a boolean variable `on` and returns the value of the assignment, that is `boolean false` - hence the expression has type `boolean` and the code compiles.

Comment: Actually eclipse stil says toString has an error and I don't know how to correct it :(

Comment: When you say "it doesn't work", what exactly are you seeing?  What results are you getting?

Comment: Basically it "works" in that the fan properties go to the screen but if the fan is off, the only thing that's supposed to show on the screen is "Fan is off" but regardless of whether the fan is on or off, this never happens...

Comment: Supposed to be off? 
`fan1.setOn(true);`

Comment: Okey I got the whole thing to work now. My final question is why is it only necessary to invoke set methods and NOT the get ones from main?

Comment: Do you even understand the question you are asking? What are `get` and `set` methods for? You are using setters to set variable values. You are building an object and printing its toString(). You will use getters if you actually need to get something.

Comment: As others have said, you don't need to use the getters and setters at all within the class.  However, for complicated objects, there may be side effects to a setter, and if you build that side effect into a setter, you would always want to use the setter.  Also, for later refactoring, it may be cleaner to use getters/setters, rather than referring to the value directly.

Comment: Clearly I was misunderstanding some stuff about getters and setters before. Thanks a lot for the explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as you are in this class body you can access everything (except for static can not access non-static). That means that you can easily set and get variables like that:

```
var = <value>;
System.out.println(var);
```

However nobody stops you from using the accessor methods - getter and setters. It is just not required.

One final note:

```
if(on = false)
```

This will always fail - it does assignment to false and then checks the newly assigned value (which is false). You need to check for equality here. Like that:

```
if(on == false)
```

Or even better:

```
if(!on)
```

Comment: @GETah you're wrong.  Java compile allows anything inside `if` that evaluates to type `boolean`.  If you are not sure, just try it for yourself.

Comment: @All, indeed, I was wrong! I had an extension blocking this kind of code, my bad...

Answer (score 0):

I just copied-pasted your code into a new file and compiled it.  It compiled and ran.  The output was

```
$ java Fan
Fan Properties:
Fan speed: 3
Color: yellow
Radius: 10.0
```

This is because the comparison in your `toString` method is wrong.  It should be as following:

```
public String toString(){
    if(on)
        return "Fan Properties:\n" + "Fan speed: " + speed + "\n"
        + "Color: " + color + "\n"
        + "Radius: " + radius + "\n";
    else
        return "Fan is off.";
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh, thanks, yeah now if works. Also, why is it not necessary to call get methods and only set methods from main?

Comment: @ProgrammingKeener Getters and setters are always optional.  Your `toString` method is part of the class, therefore it can access member variables directly.  `if(on)` has exactly the same effect as `if(getOn())`.